# Web reporting from SQL Server

Tags: reporting, sql-server, web

I have a query that mines all the Initial, Debit, Credit, and Final balance of our accounts for a specific month and year, I was given the opportunity to pick up any software/technology to report this data on a web browser (IE preferably).

Now the features I would like to have in this report is the ability to click an account and to either dropdown/newtab/newwindow all the banking transactions related to this account during the specified month and year. I would also like to have an exporting tool/button to load up the results in an Excel spreadsheet.

I've read about several options but I'm looking for something simple and preferably free/open source since I doubt I'll get the license of a software just to test it out.

I'm only posting tables I don't need fancy stuff like diagrams or graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Most BI/Reporting tools have a trial period you can use to test it, so you can easily test many and pick the one that better fits your needs; in any case, i recommend you to test [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), as it lets you do what you want to do easily, because it lets you design your reports (and in your case, your data grids) by pure drag and drop, from the query to the final design of the report.

For your particular case, you can even use your existing queries by just pasting them in DBxtra, [then create a special hyper link column to link to other reports](http://dbxtra.com/documentation/#topic/report-designer/data-grid/data_grid_formatting.htm) in the web interface (The Report Web Service), and then export the data to Excel by just clicking a button; you can also, alternatively, use the [XL Reporting add on](http://dbxtra.com/excel-reporting-service.htm), to use your queries directly into Excel, without the need to download your data from the web interface.

Finally, you can fully test all the features it has for 30 days so you can be sure it works out for you.

P.S. I'm a DBxtra evangelist.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Report Platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/report) is an option to consider.

1. Click an account and see the banking transactions for that account: Can be done using Report Filters
2. Export data to Excel: Excel export is included by default

[image: Report With Filters]

[image: Report exported to Excel]

The report platform and more are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

The licensing cost is not expensive even otherwise. Note: I work for Syncfusion.